# Double association in Sequelize model

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have these associations

```
// Tasks.js
sequelize.models.tasks.belongsTo(sequelize.models.users, {
    foreignKey: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'ASSIGNEE',
        allowNull: true
    },
    as: 'assignee'
});

sequelize.models.tasks.belongsTo(sequelize.models.users, {
    foreignKey: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'REPORTER',
        allowNull: true
    },
    as: 'reporter'
});

// Users.js
sequelize.models.users.hasMany(sequelize.models.tasks, { as: 'assignee' });
sequelize.models.users.hasMany(sequelize.models.tasks, { as: 'reporter' });
```

These association create two FK: ASSIGNEE and REPORTER. But it also creates another one: userId.
I know this "userId" FK is default, but I don't want it. I want just these two that I described in my associations.

How can I ask sequelize to ignore the default and create just what I was expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Change in users association

```
sequelize.models.users.hasMany(sequelize.models.tasks, { as: 'assignee' ,foreignKey :'ASSIGNEE'});
sequelize.models.users.hasMany(sequelize.models.tasks, { as: 'reporter' ,foreignKey :'REPORTER'});
```